# where can i look for good rails authentication example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

First i tried https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example.git  and that does not work and so i tried https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Example-Applications and it worked but it does not have activation of user once sign up is completed. So i am looking for an example with activation of user from mail. so please tell me if there are any other example that is properly working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the devise example works good. And these are the changes that i did

`config.mailer = "Devise::Mailer"` should be uncommented in devise.rb file and the following lines to be included in production.rb and development.rb file in environment folder.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
        :tls => true,
        :enable_starttls_auto => true,
        :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
        :port => "587",
        :domain => "gmail.com",
        :authentication => :plain,
        :user_name => "xxxxx@gmail.com",
        :password => "yyyyyy"
    }
```

Now it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby toolbox provides a good selection,

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication

Although if I were to express an opinion I'd use Devise

Comment: I tried devise example that was present in github and when sign up is completed i could see the confirmation link in terminal and what should i do to receive in mail.

Comment: make sure your mail config settings are set correctly. I guess your in development mode, which doesn't send email as default, but spits out message in console. This is a separate question though...

Comment: Yes i did not make any mail settings. Can you please tell me what changes need to be done.

Comment: I suggest you look at the docs: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise. Specifically `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }` line

Answer (score 0):

Devise does have an activation feature it is called confirmation.

To activate it add the :confirmable module to your model and set confirm_within to 0 in the devise configuration file.

Comment: I tried devise example that was present in github and when sign up is completed i could see the confirmation link in terminal and what should i do to receive in mail.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

and http://railscasts.com/episodes/21-super-simple-authentication

and devise http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

Good luck!